# Kafka Connection Timeout When Reached Over Internet

Tags: networking

When I try to reach a Kafka instance over the internet, using the Kafka console consumer/producer. I get timeout error.

Ping to the server is around 190ms. The port is reachable. I have telnet to it with no problem.

I run the command:

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list example.com:9092 --topic mytopic
```

The `>` prompt appears & I type in some message. After 60 seconds, this error is given:

> ERROR Error when sending message to topic mytopic with key: null, value: 5 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.

Same command works like a charm when I SSH into the server and run a console producer from inside the server (or even another server with low ping time).

I need to connect to my Kafka instance from my laptop during my development. How do I solve this?

Comment: Also an `apache-kafka` tag would be nice to have!

Comment: Not sure if these questions are on topic here – Kafka is a developer tool. There are more than 14,000 Kafka questions on [SO]. Feel free to flag your question for migration.

Comment: That said – and I have no experience with Kafka –, make sure that the port you are connecting to is reachable from the outside (9092).

Comment: I started by trying to ask in stackoverflow but before I ask the question, this "guide" comes up & says if your question is in the category of "I need to troubleshoot some software or hardware" superuser is the place to ask it!

Comment: The port is reachable. I have telnet to it, no problem.

Comment: I can see why you'd be tempted to ask on Super User, but you're unlikely to find suitable help here if most Kafka users are on [SO].